# gui in python using kivy. button, entry and labels are lacking of proper gui arrangement

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

while I'm making a gui using kivy, the button, entry and the labels are not coming properly .The inside code is not running. the expected image is attached. All the labels and the buttons are coming in the same grid, which is not expected. 
Can you help me ? I am the beginner of python. Thanks in advance friends.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

class Gui(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Content')) 
        self.add_widget(Label(text='subcontent1'))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='subcontent2'))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='subcontent3'))
        #self.add_widget(Label(text='send_button'))

class ConnectPart(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.column = 2
        self.add_widget(Button(text='send_button'))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='subcontent1'))
        self.add_widget(Entry(text='subcontent2'))
        self.add_widget(Entry(text='subcontent3'))


class This_Is_The_Application(App):

    def build(self):
        return Screen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    This_Is_The_Application().run()
```

[gui image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnM3w.png)

Comment: Proper item arrangement in Kivy  takes some practice and patience. I suggest you follow some tutorials first.

Comment: your code does not run; I am guessing you have to replace `Screen` with `Gui` throughout your application (better to use `Gui` because `Screen` is a module that exists in kivy already). Other than that you should start reading about `size_hint`-s and positions, and maybe nest some layouts..

Comment: It is hard to help you if you do not specify how the end result should look like. Please add that.